# simple injector - inject into IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, simple-injector, ihttphandler

I'm trying to embed SimpleInjector in my WCF project (I've followed the instructions [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wcfintegration.html)). Till now everything went well except from IHttpHandler issue:
the current implementation uses IHttpHandler which in turn uses MyServiceWrapper static instance:

```
public class IsAliveHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private const string SERVER_ERROR = "Bad";
    private const string SERVER_OK = "OK";

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var quoteSucceeded = false;
        var isLastLoginSucceeded = MyServiceWrapperContainer.Manager.IsLastLoginSucceeded;
//More logic here ...
    }
}
```

Now, since I moved my application to use the SimpleInjector DI mechanism I can't use such a static access since I want to use the same instance as held by the DI container. 
constructor injection here gets exception:

```
[MissingMethodException: Constructor on type '***.Applications.MyServiceWrapperService.KeepAliveHandler.IsAliveHandler' not found.]
```

**Is there a way to use container in such scenario? Are there alternatives?**

Generally, I can understand that such problem is smell of using state, but currently this is the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IsAliveHandler` can't have any constructor arguments (this is a constraint of your application framework).

Instead, you should make your `IsAliveHandler` a [Humble Object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) and consider it to be part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

This means that you extract all interesting logic out of the `IsAliveHandler` (e.g. into an `IsAliveService`) and change `IsAliveHandler` to something as follows:

```
public class IsAliveHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Bootstrapper.Container.GetInstance<IsAliveService>().Process(context);
    }
}
```

In other words, the only thing you let the `IsAliveHandler` do is to request the service from the DI Container and invoke the appropriate method on that resolved service.

Do note that `IsAliveHandler` should stay completely stateless: the resolve `IsAliveService` should nowhere be stored. You should leave it up to the DI Container to provide you with the correct instance.

In case this operation runs outside the context of a Simple Injector `Scope`, you might to wrap the operation inside such a `Scope`:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(Bootstrapper.Container))
    {
        Bootstrapper.Container.GetInstance<IsAliveService>().Process(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your good insights! Regarding the service locator you suggested in the Handler: Currently I use the container in the composition root as: `public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        private readonly Container _container = new Container();` . As you wrote in your code: `Bootstrapper.Container.GetInstance` - Should I move the container to the static Bootstrapper class?

Comment: You can place the Container abywhere you like, as long as only the start-up path of the application (can) gets a hold of it. Using the Container within the Composition Root is [not](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) the Service Locator anti-pattern. Your handler can be considered part of the Composition Root. That's why you should extract all (business) logic out of the handler.